# Does Space Exploration beta enforce a question ban?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I have been looking around the site for several days now, and no where I have I seen any mention of a question asking ban. By saying question asking ban, I mean the ban enforced when a user repeatedly ask bad questions. I have searched the help center page, and [have found  no mention whatsoever](https://space.stackexchange.com/help) of a question asking ban. I've also searched the Space Exploration meta site for any mention of the ban, and there is none. Does Space Exploration beta not have a question asking ban? Or is there a ban, but most users already knows this?

Comment: Are you referring to this: [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](http://space.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: @kimholder yep. That was exactly what I'd was talking about.I guess my searching skills are lousy.